# Experiencing graphic drivers crash, PC unusable

Tags: drivers, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

I have been experiencing a weird problem for the last week and I can't find any other poster who has the same thing.

My drivers crash, normal black screen, then recover and then immediately recrash and then recover, meaning there are 2 notifications for the crash after it all ends.

Thing is I'm quite ok with the occasional crash, but this is not occasional any more. And they DON'T crash when I'm starting up some game, they crash every time I boot my pc. Every single time for the last 10 days or so. After the crash, anything resembling graphics in my pc gets corrupted and unusable, can't use share screen on skype, can't watch youtube videos because they stutter, and worst of all there is no sound.

I have a GIGABYTE GTX 770 OC Windforcex3 and the drivers I have installed are the latest. Cleaning up previous drivers didn't help, installing them again also didn't. Checked my services to see if something was disabled there but nothing.

What I am seeking here is either a way to fix this problem altogether or a way for me to bring my PC back to normal without having to restart every time this happens. Boot time after the crash is significantly longer. I have to restart because as I said before it is almost unusable. After the restart, nothing goes wrong. It only happens on the first boot after the night or a long enough period of time.

Drivers are fully updated of course.

Thanks in advance.

PS. I am not in a position where I can meddle with the hardware and interchange GPUs as I have no spare parts.

Comment: Have you checked Windows Update? Been a handful of times that an update has screwed how my gfx runs.

Comment: Well, it says my pc is up to date as of yesterday. Do you want me to check something more specific?

Comment: I would check to see if an update was installed around the time it started playing up. Could be a .NET framework update that messes with the drivers. Also, do you have an old hard drive laying about? Install win on that and test. Need to rule out hardware issues.

Comment: Most latest batch of updates were 90% Office compatibility ones. There was a bundled update for Windows 10 version 1511, x64 systems though. Trying my best to translate the update names here, not my main language.
Also no, I am not able to do that. :/ 
Any diagnostics I could run so we could narrow this down?

Comment: When this whole thing started, my PC would restart completely by itself. Then after one or two days, only the drivers crashed.

Comment: Hmm, sounds hardware related. Forgot to ask, try disabling or removing the gfx card and use onboard gfx to test (hoping you have onboard gfx).

Comment: Agree it could be hardware and maybe over heating. Do as Papa suggested and also checking the fans. Possible thermal past on CPU. I've had similar issue before where I took the cover off and had desktop fan directed at the motherboard and gfx card to stabilize.

Comment: Alright I will try to recreate the problem, but as I said, the crash happens after my PC stays off for a lengthy period of time. So I will comment on how that went tommorow. Luckily I have HD 2000.

Apart from that though, do you know if I could do anything to avoid having to restart? Sometimes I have started working and it is a hassle to close everything and then wait for all the IDEs to start again. 

I tried restarting every service that said NVIDIA,from services.msc and devman, but had no luck. The most annoying thing is the lack of sound. My headphones get sound but my speakers don't.

Comment: If you're having hardware issues, it's not much you can do honestly. Now that you're talking about no sound etc, I'm leaning towards a motherboard problem. bokken74 talks about heating. I would check running temps with HWMonitor or in BIOS.

Comment: We get like 40 degrees celsius these days here in Greece. Yeah, my PC is definitely overheating. Checked with HWMonitor yesterday when Android Studio was acting up and hogged like 90% of my CPU and the temps were at the mid 80s, which is bad. Is it because when the PC is off it gets heated up and only when I boot it starts cooling down? Also what could be a temporary solution to this? Open the case and point a fan at it to see if it still happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For overheating I would do the following:

- Clean CPU/GFX fans and heatsinks of any dust. This will help in the short term.
- If your case has filters for air flow, clean those.
- Opening case on hot days would help.
- The end game would be to buy a good air cooler and redo your thermal paste as it's been running at high temps which can degrade the efficiency.

I live in Sydney, Australia and we get similar temps. I had 20c drop when I bought a Cooler Master Hyper 212X CPU cooler with noticeable noise reduction. It's not expensive.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yeah turns out the culprit was the heatsink, it has sooo much dust in it that you could barely see that it existed. Cleaned that up and had a 20c drop, all is good now no crashes or beeps from the case. Thanks!